# Php Mongodate Converting Date to 1970

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodate

Hello guys I 'm storing date in mongodb. The problem that I'm facing is that the date time string that I get. I try to convert it into mongodate but it converts it to `0.00000000 2016`. Here is the code

```
 $params['start'] = new MongoDate($params['start']);
        $params['end'] = new MongoDate($params['end']);
```

The string bring the date time in this form `2016-04-07 19:49:50` but after the conversion it becomes like this `0.00000000 2016`. Please tell me what is it that I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Per the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodate.php), MongoDate expects a timestamp value like `1460058590`, not a string like `2016-04-07 19:49:50`.

```
$params['start'] = new MongoDate(strtotime($params['start']));
```

Comment: I'm converting the date like this before doing this date('Y-m-d H:i:s' ,   strtotime($startD))

Comment: Then you can cut out that step and just use "new MongoDate(strtotime($startD))", and it will accomplish the same concept as this answer: using the timestamp.

Comment: @garden "Doctor, it hurts when I do this!" "Well, stop doing that." And read the documentation.

Comment: @garden We don't need more code. We've explained your issue, and the fix. Your MongoDate calls need to be passed a valid UNIX timestamp.

Answer (score 3):

The [`MongoDate` constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodate.construct.php) expects the time in Unix epoch seconds, not a time string.

> `public MongoDate::__construct ([ int $sec = time() [, int $usec = 0 ]] )`

You'll need to convert your time string using [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) or [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php).  The example code from the constructor documentation even includes an example:

```
$d = new MongoDate(strtotime("2009-05-01 00:00:01"));
echo "$d\n";
```

Comment: Beat you to it by four seconds but yours is better. :-p Have an upvote.